# Phone verification using Nexmo in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

While trying to do phone verification using Nexmo SMS gateway in Kotlin, my app crashes when I click on the confirm button. I am testing in the emulator.

After adding their library, the code look like this:

```
lateinit var confirm : Button

var httpConfig = HttpConfig.builder()
    .apiBaseUri("https://api.example.com")
    .restBaseUri("https://rest.example.com")
    .snsBaseUri("https://sns.example.com")
    .build()

var client = NexmoClient.Builder()
    .apiKey("3***********")
    .apiSecret("m5**************")
    .httpConfig(httpConfig)
    .build()

var verifyClient = client.verifyClient

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone)

    confirm = findViewById(R.id.confirm)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    confirm.setOnClickListener {
        val request = VerifyRequest("966540844076", "Vonage")
        request.length = 4

        val response = verifyClient.verify(request)

        if (response.status == VerifyStatus.OK) {
            System.out.printf("RequestID: %s", response.requestId)
        } else {
            System.out.printf(
                "ERROR! %s: %s",
                response.status,
                response.errorText
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to verify this phone number using the `curl` command, as explained in the [Verify Overview](https://developer.nexmo.com/verify/overview#write-the-code) section of the Vonage documentation. You could also use a tool for API testing for this, like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/). This way you can make sure the API key and secret are working.